# Custom Formdata matching with user table

Tags: plugins, forms, input

I am writing a code to match form input data with user table in wp, but its not working proper, either condition is true or false, its giving same message. please help me to resolve it.

```
  function email_form_code() {
    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Email (required) <br />';
    echo '<input type="email" name="email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}

function checkpoint_email() {
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
    if(!is_email($email)) {
        echo '<div class="error"><p>Invalid e-mail!</p></div>';
     }
    $datum = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp8p_users WHERE $current_user->user_email = $email");
    if($datum < 0) {
       echo "Email Verified";
    }
    else {
         echo "Email Not Verified";
    }   
}
}
function ec_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    checkpoint_email();
    email_form_code();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'av_email_cform', 'ec_shortcode' );
?>
```

Comment: When you say it always gives the same message, is that the verified message or the not verified message?

Comment: True or False, in every condition its give same message "Email Verified"

Comment: and if we add use !== in condition then its shows "Email Not Verified" every time, its true or False, give the same message.

Comment: And where is the form the `$_POST` data coming from? Have you checked the values of `$_POST['email']` and the current user email to confirm they have the expected values? Is the user logged in?

Comment: yes. user is logged in. you may check it at learn.amarverma.com/email

it will show guest message, once u log in, it will show user name and email id and below a input field to accept email id.

I want to check and verfiy this input email id which is stored in user table. i have this task to  complete.

Comment: you may check form codes from below image

http://prntscr.com/rijmeq

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as text, questions need to be self contained as people don't always read comments, and an image on another website can be broken, isn't accessible, and i have to type it all out from scratch if I want to reproduce the problem

Comment: @TomJNowell Question edited, please have a look and let me know what I am missing.

Comment: `submit` is an extremely generic name for a form input, you should change it to something specific so it doesn't get triggered accidentally. Also, you have a `<`, what happens if a user is found and the value is 1? `1 < 0` is false, 1 is always larger than 0, not smaller than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional check is the wrong way around, it should be `>` not `<`.

But more importantly, why are you doing a raw SQL query at all, just use the standard functions, e.g. `get_user_by`:

```php
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
if ( !$user ) {
    // there is no user with that email
}
```

---

Also, `submit` is an incredibly generic name for a form input to check, use something more specific, like `av_email_cform_submit`.

You can also replace your `action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '"` with `action=""`. You also have a double `<p><p>` in your form.

Comment: Thanks a Ton! I was looking for its solution since long time. Thanks again.

Comment: one issues is there. if I logged in my account, and I put other  email id which is stored in database, its showing verified. I want Current user can only verify his email id only. so please guide how to restrict by current user only.

Comment: ooh, neither this answer nor your original code checks the current user specifically, you should ask how to get the current users email in a new Q

Comment: problem solved. Thanks for your guidance. Is there any tutorial/coding to create a plugin for scheduled popup?